# Parse PFuser already logged in skip te login view controller

Tags: parse-platform, authentication

I am trying to skip over my login view once a user is logged in. How can I check to see if a user is logged in through Parse while the app is starting? And how I can skip the LoginViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
PFUser.currentUser()
```

According to [Parse Documentation](http://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html#/c:objc(cs)PFUser(cm)currentUser)

> Returns a PFUser that is the currently logged in user. If there is
>   none, returns nil.

After that you have 3 options:

**First**

On your LoginViewController, you check if the currentUser() exists, if it does, you perform the segue for the main app viewController.

*Tip*: Use a present instead of a push, so the user can't come back to the login screen.

**Second**
On the main viewController you check if the currentUser is nil, if it's you present the LoginViewController.

For both cases, do it in the ViewDidLoad method, and don't animate, so the user will not perceive the transaction.

**third**
On the AppDelegate on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

This will check if the currentUser() is nil, if does, the app will present the loginViewController instead of the default initialisation.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let loginViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
        self.window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: yeah i had that already, but how can i say that the loginviewcontroller doesn't have to be displayed again when the user is logged in, and classes die app and open it again.

Comment: The most common/easy way is on your main viewController viewDidLoad you check if the currentUser() is nil, if it is, you present the loginViewController without animation.

Comment: A simple segue it's enough.

Comment: please show it like presentViewController(L, animated:false, completion: nil)

Comment: Use a segue, is easier: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html